# Moshiach, Arabia and the Eirev Rav

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, messiah, messianic-redemption

In [a comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139868/moshiach-arabia-and-the-eirev-rav?noredirect=1#comment467281_139868) in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/139793/27180), Rabbi Yitzchok Soloveitchik is said to have said that ערביא (Arabia) is referring to the Eirev Rav and their role in the End of Days.

So, according to this opinion, עירוב רב means a certain sect of religious Judaism with hashkafa that runs unreconcilably contrary to authentic Torah belief and Moshiach is groomed within that sect.

Where can this explanation of Rav Soloveitchik (or other(s) be found, and based on what sources does Rabbi Soloveitchik bases this?

Comment: Correction: Author of Hatekufa Besaaros Eliyahu is R' Yisroel Elyahu Weintraub

Comment: As the original commentor, I should make it clear that my comment was mistaken. It was not a quote from R' Weintraub, nor was it referring to this Midrash quoted by Maharal. R' Yitzchok Solovetchik shlit"a quoted a different midrash about ערביא and their role in the End of Days. R' Solovetchik explained ערביא in that context as referring to Eiruv Rav. I don't know what sources he cited for this.

Comment: @Deuteronomy My apologies, read it wrong. I am not saying it refers to a fysical place called Arabia, maybe it refers to Arabia as bnei Yishamel, e.g. the Yishmaelim. Anyway, the explanation on what it seems to have been from Rabbi Soloveitchik that it refers to the Eirev Rav, is what got my attention, and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Deuteronomy see my edit, better?

Comment: @chortkov2 Any idea where Rav Soloveitchik said this? Can I find it in any sefer?

Comment: In a live shiur to his kollel in Jerusalem. Sorry, I don't think it's published in any of his sefarim.

Comment: @chortkov2 would you maybe want to write it up as an answer? What Midrash does Rav Soloveitchik quotes, what does he say etc? Since we don't have an written piece, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

The notion that עירוב רב refers to a sect of religious Jews is found in the hakdama to the עץ חיים. There it means Jews who speak Lashon Hara about קבלה.

See [here](https://research.library.fordham.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1008&context=emw) and search for "mixed multitude".

Comment: Thank you, but I was specifically looking for the link with Arabians and Erev Rav.